# Selecting div with a certain number of children

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I want to select every div of a certain class with more than 14 spans inside. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('span').size() > 14
});
```

I'm not sure you can select on the count of elements, unfortunately.

Here's a [fiddle in action](http://jsfiddle.net/K6hQd/).

Answer (score 5):

```
var $divs = $('div span:nth-child(15)').parents("div");
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brian3f/gK6eG/2/

Comment: Oh I like this. Different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant, but this works. Used limit of 2 to make it easier on my fiddle typing:

html:

```
<div id="div2">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div id="div3">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>

<div id="results"></div>
```

js:

```
var the_divs = [];
$( 'div' ).each(function(){
   if( $( this).children('span').length > 2 )
       the_divs.push( $( this ).attr('id') );
});

$( 'div#results' ).text( the_divs.join( ', ' ) );
```

result:

```
div1, div3
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JBA9y/

Comment: you should be required to comment when down voting

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.class").filter(function(){ return $("span",this).length===14}).addClass("yahoo");
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E86e5/4/

Comment: no clue. but I like the filtering action you and Stefan are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery size or length for refrence and example refer http://api.jquery.com/size/